# Loading Dynamic data into modal body affects all other modal bodys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading data from my database into a bootstrap modal using Ajax. All of that is working fine. My issue is that after I open the modal that loads all the info from the database, whenever i open another modal on the page... It displays that modal body as well.

Modal:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="userInfo.php?id='.$user['uid'].'" id="openUserInfoModal">View</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="userInfoModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Info</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#openUserInfoModal').on('click',function(){
          var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
          $('.modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
              $('#userInfoModal').modal({show:true});
          });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define your modal body with an id then do the javascript code on it

```
 <div id="modal-one" class="modal-body">
```

Then with JavaScript convert

```
    $('#modal-one.modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
          $('#userInfoModal').modal({show:true});
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the modals body more directly:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#openUserInfoModal').on('click',function(){
      var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
      $('#openUserInfoModal .modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
          $('#userInfoModal').modal({show:true});
      });
  });
});
```

I have added `#openUserInfoModal` to line 4 of your JS.